# Error mounting disk image using guestmount

Tags: mount, filesystem, virtualization, disk, disk-image

In trying to get `qemubuilder` to work, I'm using [`guestmount`](http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html) to mount an image (`base-i386.qemu`) on a temporary directory (`/run/shm/qemu.3430`) without needing root permissions.

I am running Ubuntu Precise 32-bit.

The disk image and empty temp folder already exist:

```
user@host:/scratch/qemubuilder$ file base-i386.qemu 
base-i386.qemu: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=6d00c1e4-8b63-4bed-89d9-1a28b1dfd9ed (large files)
```

Following [the examples](http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html#examples), I tried running:

```
user@host:/scratch/qemubuilder$ guestmount -a base-i386.qemu -i /run/shm/qemu.3430/
warning: Unable to get device geometry for /var/tmp/guestfs.4SXaJV/root
febootstrap-supermin-helper: ext2: parent directory not found: /lib: File not found by ext2_lookup
libguestfs: error: external command failed, see earlier error messages
```

I get the same error if I manually create the image:

```
user@host:/scratch/qemubuilder$ dd if=/dev/null bs=1M seek=1024 of=testimg
[...]
user@host:/scratch/qemubuilder$ mkfs.ext4 testimg
[...]
user@host:/scratch/qemubuilder$ file testimg
testimg: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=47872462-214b-43ce-8a03-69c4c1572990 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
user@host:/scratch/qemubuilder$ guestmount -a testimg -i /run/shm/qemu.3430/
warning: Unable to get device geometry for /var/tmp/guestfs.R1UkyW/root
febootstrap-supermin-helper: ext2: parent directory not found: /lib: File not found by ext2_lookup
libguestfs: error: external command failed, see earlier error messages
datbite@shadow:/scratch/qemubuilder
```

I see [a bug that gave the same symptoms](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libguestfs/+bug/930634), but it is marked fixed with the versions I have.

How can I mount my image?

Answer (score 3):

```
febootstrap-supermin-helper: ext2: parent directory not found: /lib: File not found by ext2_lookup
```

There are two places where this could be printed:

Either when supermin runs out of disk space on /tmp or /var/tmp.

Or when you need to update the appliance (only on Debian/Ubuntu) which you can do this way:

```
sudo update-guestfs-appliance
```

Yes, it's an obscure internal error and we are planning on making the message better:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=965524

and also removing this pitfall from the Debian packaging.